# Define an UDF in PySpark where the return type is based on a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have to extract data from REST API and then transform the results as table. For reference, I use this [link](https://github.com/jamesshocking/Spark-REST-API-UDF). My problem comes from the definition of the schema from the link. Here is an example.

```
def executeRestApi(verb, url, headers, body):
  #
  headers = {
      'content-type': "application/json"
  }

  res = None
  # Make API request, get response object back, create dataframe from above schema.
  try:
    if verb == "get":
      res = requests.get(url, data=body, headers=headers)
    else:
      res = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
  except Exception as e:
    return e

  if res != None and res.status_code == 200:
    return json.loads(res.text)

  return None

schema = StructType([
  StructField("Count", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("Message", StringType(), True),
  StructField("SearchCriteria", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Results", ArrayType(
    StructType([
      StructField("Make_ID", IntegerType()),
      StructField("Make_Name", StringType())
    ])
  ))
])
```

Here is the definition of the UDF:

```
udf_executeRestApi = udf(executeRestApi, schema)
```

In my case, the schema varies for each REST API. I have a table that I store table name and schema:

```
my_table = spark.createDataFrame([["A", "schema_A", "get"], ["B", "schema_B", "get"]], schema=["TableName", "Schema", "verb"])\
    .withColumn("url", F.concat(F.lit("my_url/"), F.col("TableName")))
+---------+--------+----+--------+
|TableName|  Schema|verb|     url|
+---------+--------+----+--------+
|        A|schema_A| get|my_url/A|
|        B|schema_B| get|my_url/B|
+---------+--------+----+--------+
```

How can I apply:

```
my_table.withColumn("result", udf_executeRestApi(col("verb"), col("url"), col("headers"), col("body")))
```

where the schema is based on the column `Schema`?

Comment: Hey, the issue here is that the schema for the column needs to be defined in PySpark, and you have different schema. The question would be what you plan to do with a DataFrame that has mismatched schema? This feels like an intermediate step to something. My recommendation is to store the REST API output as a binary blob instead so that the column can remain as is. Just deserialize when you need the output for something. Does that make sense? Would an example help?

Comment: Hello Kevin, Thanks for your answer. An example would be welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

So the goal here is basically to parallelize API calls but the schema of the different APIs is a mismatch. Let's not start with Spark first. We can write the code in Python and Pandas, and then bring it to Spark with [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) easily.

For first some setup. I am using the pokemon API to get an end to end example. Assume that the URLs are different though. We are not concerned about Schema first.

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, Iterable, Any, Dict
import requests as re
import pickle

df = pd.DataFrame({"table": ["ditto", "pikachu"], 
                   "verb": ["get", "get"], 
                   "url":["https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto",
                          "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu"]})
```

We can make the logic for one row in the Pandas DataFrame to do an API call. Instead of extracting the schema, we can just use pickle to make a binary type column that holds all the result.

```py
def call_api(df: List[Dict[str,Any]]) -> Iterable[Dict[str,Any]]:
    # this is for one function call
    # if the dataframe coming in is a list of dict, this operation is easy
    # lets assume df has one row
    row = df[0]
    res = re.get(row["url"])
    row["result"] = pickle.dumps(res.text)
    yield row
```

Fugue can now read the annotations and apply the conversion. All we have to do is use the `transform` function to test:

```py
from fugue import transform
transform(df.iloc[0:1], call_api, schema="*,result:binary")
```

Schema is a requirement for Spark so we need it here also. This will give you something like this:

```
table   verb    url     result
ditto   get     https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto 
b'\x80\x04\x95\xc2X\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x...
```

It's misaligned but notice the result is binary. This works for one row so how do we apply it on each row? We just pass in a partitioning strategy.

```py
transform(df, call_api, schema="*,result:binary", partition={"by":"url"})
```

I don't know what column you will partition on, but the goal is 1 row per partition and then we can parallelize the rows of the DataFrame. In my example here, url is unique.

And then now we can bring it to Spark. We just need to pass in a SparkSession to the same `transform` call and it will run on Spark.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = transform(df, call_api, schema="*,result:binary", partition={"by":"url"},engine=spark)
sdf.show()
```

This will give the output.

A couple of notes:

1. If you want to use the API result later, just unpickle the column to the original form. Use pickle.loads
2. If you want to subset the result before pickle, just add the logic to `call_api` and have some if else also
3. The schema expression for Fugue `transform()` will be converted to Spark's schema expression.

If you need anymore help, feel free to message me. Contact info in profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's an interesting idea. I finally found another solution by using built-in SQL function